Mitsubishi FX5U MC Protocol Batch Write Only Writes to First 32-bit Address
I'm using the MC protocol to write 32-bit (DWord) data from a PC to my Mitsubishi FX5U PLC. Below is an example of a command that works, followed by a similar one that doesn't work as expected. The goal is to write values to multiple 32-bit addresses (R0, R2, R4, etc.), but only the first address (R0) gets written.
Working Code Example:
This command successfully writes the value 5 to R0:
string command = "500000FF03FF000020000014010000R*000000000200050000";
byte[] commandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
await TcpClient.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(commandBytes), 
SocketFlags.None);

This command successfully writes the value 5 to R0.
Non-working Code Example:
Now, we will see the code where I try to write data to 3 addresses (R0, R2, R4), but no data gets written.
string command = "500000FF03FF000020000014010000R*0000000006000500000005000000050000";
byte[] commandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
await TcpClient.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(commandBytes), 
SocketFlags.None);

Why is the second command unable to write, and why doesn't it write to R0, R2, and R4? I'm trying to write 32-bit data to multiple addresses. Are there any specific changes needed in the command structure or protocol settings to achieve this? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

What is the function code you use?

The function code I'm using is 1401 (Batch write in word units), as seen in the command:
500000FF03FF000020000014010000R*000000000200050000.
Is this the correct function code for writing multiple 32-bit (DWord) data to consecutive addresses? Should there be any additional settings or modifications to properly handle 32-bit data across multiple registers like R0, R2, and R4?
